# Valuation rings (confusion with arithmetics)

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory

I am reading Goldschmidt's Algebraic functions and projective curves. From the book:

Let $K$ be a field. An integral domain $\mathcal{O}\subset K$ is a valuation ring if for all $x\in K$ either $x$ or $x^{-1}$ is in $\mathcal{O}$. The valuation afforded by $\mathcal{O}$ is the natural map $\nu: K^\times\rightarrow K^\times/\mathcal{O}^\times$, where $\cdot^\times$ is the group of units. Accordingly we define a total order on $V:=K^\times/\mathcal{O}^\times$ by $\underline{a\mathcal{O}^\times\le b\mathcal{O}^\times}$ if $\underline{a^{-1}b\in\mathcal{O}}$.

Now my question: I wish to verify that $\nu(a+b) \ge \min\{\nu(a),\nu(b)\}$, but I am a bit lost in which operations take place in which structure.

I think the addition in $\nu(a+b)$ means that we write $K^\times$ additively. However the first underlined part seems to indicate that we write $K^\times$ multiplicative. Furthermore in what structure does the multiplication in the second underlined part take place?

Can somebody help to clarify the constructions after which I hope to be able to prove that $\nu(a+b) \ge \min\{\nu(a),\nu(b)\}$. Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: The book states that it writes $V$ additively.

Comment: You want to show that if you take $a,b\in K^\times$, then either $a+b$ is zero (in which case $v(a+b)$ is infinity, so the proposition is true), or $v(a+b)\geqslant\{v(a),v(b)\}$. As a group you want to think of $K^\times$ multiplicatively, but that doesn't stop you from adding things. For example, consider $K=\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. The valuation is then the usual $p$-adic one. The statement $v(a+b)\geqslant\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$ is then intuitively saying "the sum of two things is divisible by at least the smallest power of $p$ that divides both $a$ and $b$".

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but you wrote that $\;\nu: K^\times\to K^\times/\mathcal O^\times\;$ , so $\;\nu(a)\;$ and all that happens in that quotient ring...

Comment: I tried to prove the inequality. Say $\nu(a)\le\nu(b)$. Then to show $\nu(a+b)\ge\nu(a)$ I look at $a^{-1}(a+b)$ and have to show that it is in $\mathcal{O}$. However I do not know how to proceed from here, because I don't understand how to combine the multiplication and addition in this case. One option: Since $a+b$ takes place in $K^\times$, this addition is equal to the multiplication is $K$ and so actually $a^{-1}(a+b) = a^{-1}(ab) = b$? Or we just work out the brackets and get $(1+a^{-1}b)$? The second one sounds more logical, but from there on I do not understand what element I am

Comment: dealing with and how to proceed.

Comment: @Marc By assumption that $v(a)\leqslant v(b)$ you know that $a\mathcal{O}\leqslant b\mathcal{O}$ so that $a^{-1}b\in\mathcal{O}$. To show that $v(a+b)\geqslant v(a)$, you want to show that $a^{-1}(a+b)\in\mathcal{O}$, but $a^{-1}(a+b)=1+a^{-1}b$. Both $1$ and $a^{-1}b$ are in $\mathcal{O}$, so there sum is as well.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. I now also understand your first reply:)

Comment: @Marc Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to have this answered.

You want to show that $v(a+b)\geqslant\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$. WLOG you can assume $v(a)\leqslant v(b)$. By definition, this means that $a^{-1}b\in\mathcal{O}$. To show that $v(a+b)\geqslant v(a)$, it suffices to show that $a^{-1}(a+b)\in\mathcal{O}$. But, $a^{-1}(a+b)=1+a^{-1}b$. But, $1,a^{-1}b\in\mathcal{O}$ so $1+a^{-1}b\in\mathcal{O}$.